# runas become returns Win32ErrorCode 1314: A required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: ansible, windows-10, winrm

and thanks in advance for reading and support.
I keep running into the error mentioned in title when using `runas` as become method from my Ansible controller towards Win10 Pro 22H2 host. I did my research on various forum resources, but none of them solved my case.

Is someone able to tell me what I am doing wrong? I am providing info about my lab setup below.
Many thanks in advance;

Output from `ansible -i win_inventory.yaml W10-testhost -m win_whoami -k -bK -vvv` command:

```
The full traceback is:
Exception calling "CreateProcessAsUser" with "9" argument(s): "CreateProcessWithTokenW() failed (A required privilege is not held by the client, Win32ErrorCode 1314)"
At line:103 char:5
+     $result = [Ansible.Become.BecomeUtil]::CreateProcessAsUser($usern ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception

ScriptStackTrace:
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 103
at <ScriptBlock><End>, <No file>: line 137
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 11

System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "CreateProcessAsUser" with "9" argument(s): "CreateProcessWithTokenW() failed (A required privilege is not held by the client, Win32ErrorCode 1314)" ---> Ansible.Process.Win32Exception: CreateProcessWithTokenW() failed (A required privilege is not held by the client, Win32ErrorCode 1314)
   at Ansible.Become.BecomeUtil.CreateProcessAsUser(String username, String password, LogonFlags logonFlags, LogonType logonType, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, String lpCurrentDirectory, IDictionary environment, Byte[] stdin) in c:\Users\LocalAdmin\AppData\Local\Temp\orxfw24j.1.cs:line 309
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
W10-testhost | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "internal error: failed to become user 'LocalAdmin': Exception calling \"CreateProcessAsUser\" with \"9\" argument(s): \"CreateProcessWithTokenW() failed (A required privilege is not held by the client, Win32ErrorCode 1314)\""
}
```

Entry facts:

- Controller: Debian 11 amd64, Ansible 2.12.0, libraries:

  - python3-winrm 0.3.0-2;
  - python3-ntlm-auth 1.4.0-1;
  - python3-requests-ntlm 1.1.0-1.1;
- Win10 Pro 22H2 x64 node;
- WinRM set up with HTTPS and NTLM authentication, standard local administrator account with granted full access through `winrm configSDDL default` dialog.

PowerShell output about my WinRM listener setup:

```
Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value                                                                                                                          
----            ----                           -------------   -----                                                                                                                          
System.String   Address                                        *                                                                                                                              
System.String   Transport                                      HTTPS                                                                                                                          
System.String   Port                                           5986                                                                                                                           
System.String   Hostname                                       W10-testhost                                                                                                                   
System.String   Enabled                                        true                                                                                                                           
System.String   URLPrefix                                      wsman                                                                                                                          
System.String   CertificateThumbprint                          <Omitted hash>                                                                                       
System.String   ListeningOn_1770022257                         127.0.0.1                                                                                                                      
System.String   ListeningOn_35909171                           <Omited IPv4>                                                                                                                 
System.String   ListeningOn_1414502903                         ::1
```

PowerShell output about my WinRM service:

```
Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value                                                                                                                          
----            ----                           -------------   -----                                                                                                                          
System.String   RootSDDL                                       O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)(A;;GA;;;S-1-5-21-2796465674-2055441695-237597433-1001)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)  
System.String   MaxConcurrentOperations                        4294967295                                                                                                                     
System.String   MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser                 1500                                                                                                                           
System.String   EnumerationTimeoutms                           240000                                                                                                                         
System.String   MaxConnections                                 300                                                                                                                            
System.String   MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds                  120                                                                                                                            
System.String   AllowUnencrypted                               false                                                                                                                          
Container       Auth                                                                                                                                                                          
Container       DefaultPorts                                                                                                                                                                  
System.String   IPv4Filter                                     *                                                                                                                              
System.String   IPv6Filter                                     *                                                                                                                              
System.String   EnableCompatibilityHttpList...                 false                                                                                                                          
System.String   EnableCompatibilityHttpsLis...                 false                                                                                                                          
System.String   CertificateThumbprint                                                                                                                                                         
System.String   AllowRemoteAccess                              true
```

My inventory setup (from `-i win_inventory.yaml` file):

```
---
win10_hosts:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_become_method: runas
    ansible_become_flags: 'logon_type=interactive'
  hosts:
    W10-testhost:
      ansible_host: '<Omitted IP>'
      ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
      ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
      ansible_user: 'LocalAdmin'
      ansible_become_user: 'LocalAdmin'
...
```

Lastly, solutions I tried so far:

1. Based on official documentation, I tried using `SYSTEM` for `ansible_become_user` variable. Resulted into error `internal error: failed to become user 'SYSTEM': Exception calling \"CreateProcessAsUser\" with \"9\" argument(s): \"Failed to get token for NT AUTHORITY\\SYSTEM required for become as a service account or an account without a password\"`;
2. Disabling `Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only` policy, rebooting Win10 node and trying point 1 above again - same result;
3. Based on MS's documentation regarding `CreateProcessAsUser` and `CreateProcessWithTokenW` functions, I tried to assign the following privileges to my local administrator account and rebooting Win10 note after:

   - SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME (Replace a process-level token);
   - SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME (Adjust memory quotas for a process);
   - SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME (Impersonate a client after authentication).

Many thanks for your ideas and support.

Comment: Ansible is one of those products that may be affected by UAC in some network configurations, and need a hack for  LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/user-account-control-and-remote-restriction
 https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/42978

Comment: @GregAskew thank you for your idea. You were actually right. I was sure this has something to do with Windows, but since I am not expert enough, I haven't thought of the possibility of UAC restricting network access. It's only a partial solution, I had to add the rights mentioned above, and it started working.
I will definitely post a final solution once I will create and test a working and safe configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A final solution that worked for me, as suggested by @GregAskew and [Ansible PSexec module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/psexec_module.html).
Since my lab host was not domain-joined, I had to disable UAC remote restrictions and it started working. For use in planned production environment, I decided to disable them only temporarily. Then I am joining the production stations to AD domain and re-enabling the restrictions.

About the rights:
If you will still be getting the error regarding insufficient privileges with UAC remote restrictions disabled and station rebooted after, you will also have to add them via GPO and reboot the machine. For example in my case, the `CreateProcessAsUser` function requires `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN` privilege, and `CreateProcessWithTokenW` function requires `SE_IMPERSONATE_NAME` privileges to be held by user specified in `become_user` directive.

So finally, the resolution order I can recommend:

1. If you can, join the stations or servers to domain;
2. If not, then disable UAC remote restrictions and reboot the station after doing so;
3. If still not sufficient, assign the required privileges via GPO and reboot the station after doing so.